# Keeping a variable static in the shell script

Tags: shell, sed

Is it possible to set a static value to a variable in Putty in a shell script. I am trying to create an account using Flist used by multiple people. To use the SED command it would find and replace the account number every time. Hence a fixed acc no. needs to be searched.

Comment: Investigate the `readonly` command in the bash manual.

Comment: Do you want the script to set a value that persists across multiple invocations? It's not really clear what your use case is.

Comment: An example of what you want to do, would not harm in this question

Comment: yes I want that value to remain constant after every invocation, as in go back to the old set value after replacing it in the flist.